# include ejs with statement

Tags: javascript, nodes, ejs

I want to know if it's possible to include my header with ejs only if the user is loggin.
I tried this:

```
<% if(connect) { %>
    <%- include('../partials/header-login'); %>
<%  } else { %>
    <%- include('../partials/header'); %>
<% } %>
```

Is someone having a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right track!
From the docs:

Html template:

```
    <% if (user) { %>   <h2><%= user.name %></h2> <% } %>
```

Usage:

```
let template = ejs.compile(str, options);
template(data);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.render(str, data, options);
// => Rendered HTML string

ejs.renderFile(filename, data, options, function(err, str){
    // str => Rendered HTML string
});
```

You can see more details on the oficial documentation: https://ejs.co/#docs